# Longtable too wide, vertically centering contents

Tags: longtable, width

I've read through some questions re: `longtable` and how to make it fit the width of the page but have been unsuccessful. In the example, the table fits the width of the page but goes outside of the specified margins. MWE attached. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in}   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}             % Activate for rotated page geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                        % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}

\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{\fontsize{11}{13}\mdseries}
\usepackage[font=xipt]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\usepackage{longtable}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }                      

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8cm}|}}
\hline \textbf{Material} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline Nickel Titanium Alloy (50/50) Thin Walls & Otherwise known as Nitinol; exhibits shape memory effect--ability to undergo deformation and resume original shape above "transformation temperature"--and super elasticity \cite{borges} \\
\hline Maraging Steel & Group of steels that possesses superior strength and toughness without losing malleability; this is due to aging, which incorporates heat treatment resulting in the precipitation of intermetallic compounds \cite{degarmo} \\
\hline Aluminum Copper Alloy & Aluminum is one of the most versatile, economical, and attractive metallic materials; these alloys are most valuable for their high strength and corrosion resistance \cite{ahmad} \\
\hline Ceramic with Polyamide Coating & Polyamide coatings afford materials durability, thermal properties, chemical resistance, electrical properties, and abrasion and chemical resistance \\
\hline Amdry, Inconel 718 & High-strength corrosion-resistant nickel chromium material; age-hardened, post-weld crack resistant, and has good tensile, fatigue, creep, and rupture strength properties \cite{specialmetals} \\
\hline Stainless Steel & Notable for its corrosion and oxidation resistance; comes with various finishes to suit the applicable environment \cite{british} \\
\hline Neodymium Magnet & Strongest permanent commercial magnet available; graded according to maximum energy product (Joules per cubic meter); sintered neodymium generally not corrosion resistant \cite{fraden, wisegeek, warren} \\
\hline Hot Work Tool Steel Cubes & Group of steels used to cut or shape material at high temperatures; good hot hardness and toughness and fair wear resistance due to substantial amounts of carbide \cite{reardon} \\
\hline O-1 Tool Steel & Part of the cold work, oil-hardening tool steels group; used to materials at low temperatures possessing high hardenability and wear resistance along with average toughness and heat softening resistance \cite{machinery} \\
\hline Unknown Tensile Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is iron-chromium \\
\hline Unknown Mounted Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is silumin (aluminum-silicon alloy) \\ \hline
\caption{Analyzed Material Descriptions} \end{longtable} \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the table would look much better if you (a) were to use 'raggedright` instead of centered alignment and (b) used single-spacing. In addition, do examine the correctness of your claim that "the table fits the width of the page". In my calculations (shown in the code below), the widths of the columns must be strictly less than 8cm.

Oh, and do note that `longtable` environments are automatically centered -- no need to encase them in `center` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.5in,right=1in,vmargin=1in}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}

\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{\fontsize{11}{13}\mdseries}
\usepackage[font=xipt]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%%%\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}

\usepackage{color,soul,ragged2e}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\usepackage{longtable}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }    

% Calculate width of columns in 'longtable'      
% Width of "letterpaper" page is 8.5"       
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{3in} % 3" = (8.5"-1"-1.5")/2
\addtolength\mylen{\dimexpr-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{singlespacing} % optional but recommended
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\mylen}|}}
\hline 
\textbf{Material} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline 
\endhead

\hline
\caption{Analyzed Material Descriptions} 
\endlastfoot

Nickel Titanium Alloy (50/50) Thin Walls & Otherwise known as Nitinol; exhibits shape memory effect--ability to undergo deformation and resume original shape above "transformation temperature"--and super elasticity \cite{borges} \\
\hline 
Maraging Steel & Group of steels that possesses superior strength and toughness without losing malleability; this is due to aging, which incorporates heat treatment resulting in the precipitation of intermetallic compounds \cite{degarmo} \\
\hline 
Aluminum Copper Alloy & Aluminum is one of the most versatile, economical, and attractive metallic materials; these alloys are most valuable for their high strength and corrosion resistance \cite{ahmad} \\
\hline 
Ceramic with Polyamide Coating & Polyamide coatings afford materials durability, thermal properties, chemical resistance, electrical properties, and abrasion and chemical resistance \\
\hline 
Amdry, Inconel 718 & High-strength corrosion-resistant nickel chromium material; age-hardened, post-weld crack resistant, and has good tensile, fatigue, creep, and rupture strength properties \cite{specialmetals} \\
\hline 
Stainless Steel & Notable for its corrosion and oxidation resistance; comes with various finishes to suit the applicable environment \cite{british} \\
\hline 
Neodymium Magnet & Strongest permanent commercial magnet available; graded according to maximum energy product (Joules per cubic meter); sintered neodymium generally not corrosion resistant \cite{fraden, wisegeek, warren} \\
\hline 
Hot Work Tool Steel Cubes & Group of steels used to cut or shape material at high temperatures; good hot hardness and toughness and fair wear resistance due to substantial amounts of carbide \cite{reardon} \\
\hline 
O-1 Tool Steel & Part of the cold work, oil-hardening tool steels group; used to materials at low temperatures possessing high hardenability and wear resistance along with average toughness and heat softening resistance \cite{machinery} \\
\hline 
Unknown Tensile Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is iron-chromium \\
\hline Unknown Mounted Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is silumin (aluminum-silicon alloy) \\ 
\end{longtable} 
\end{singlespacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To vertically center the material in both columns, simply switch from `p{\mylen}` to `m{\mylen}` in the setup of the `longtable`. Speaking for myself, though, I think that top-alignment is preferable to vertical centering.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use `ltablex` (makes `tabularx` a "longtable") and then the `tabularx` colummns (as you want to use `tabularx` eitherway). Here's a picture of the output (with `showframe`, so you can see that it fits the margin):

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in,showframe}   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}             % Activate for rotated page geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                        % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}

\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{\fontsize{11}{13}\mdseries}
\usepackage[font=xipt]{caption}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }                      

\begin{document}

\begingroup\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{p{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{2}{C|}}
\hline \textbf{Material} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline Nickel Titanium Alloy (50/50) Thin Walls & Otherwise known as Nitinol; exhibits shape memory effect--ability to undergo deformation and resume original shape above "transformation temperature"--and super elasticity \cite{borges} \\
\hline Maraging Steel & Group of steels that possesses superior strength and toughness without losing malleability; this is due to aging, which incorporates heat treatment resulting in the precipitation of intermetallic compounds \cite{degarmo} \\
\hline Aluminum Copper Alloy & Aluminum is one of the most versatile, economical, and attractive metallic materials; these alloys are most valuable for their high strength and corrosion resistance \cite{ahmad} \\
\hline Ceramic with Polyamide Coating & Polyamide coatings afford materials durability, thermal properties, chemical resistance, electrical properties, and abrasion and chemical resistance \\
\hline Amdry, Inconel 718 & High-strength corrosion-resistant nickel chromium material; age-hardened, post-weld crack resistant, and has good tensile, fatigue, creep, and rupture strength properties \cite{specialmetals} \\
\hline Stainless Steel & Notable for its corrosion and oxidation resistance; comes with various finishes to suit the applicable environment \cite{british} \\
\hline Neodymium Magnet & Strongest permanent commercial magnet available; graded according to maximum energy product (Joules per cubic meter); sintered neodymium generally not corrosion resistant \cite{fraden, wisegeek, warren} \\
\hline Hot Work Tool Steel Cubes & Group of steels used to cut or shape material at high temperatures; good hot hardness and toughness and fair wear resistance due to substantial amounts of carbide \cite{reardon} \\
\hline O-1 Tool Steel & Part of the cold work, oil-hardening tool steels group; used to materials at low temperatures possessing high hardenability and wear resistance along with average toughness and heat softening resistance \cite{machinery} \\
\hline Unknown Tensile Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is iron-chromium \\
\hline Unknown Mounted Specimens & EDX analysis suggests that this unknown specimen is silumin (aluminum-silicon alloy) \\ \hline
\caption{Analyzed Material Descriptions} \end{tabularx}\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would I go about vertically centering the text in the table?